# Change css dependent on value from database

Tags: css, yii2

I've few radiobuttons in my form which I've changed css styling as below. 
formfield

```
<div class="form-inline boxradio">

                            <?php 
                                if((Yii::$app->user->can('s_newworkop') && $model->wp_status == 'Submitted') || (Yii::$app->user->can('s_newworkop') && Yii::$app->user->can('s_newworkem') && $model->wp_status == 'Assigned')){

                                    echo $form->field($model, 'wp_spost21')->radioList(
                                        ['Yes'=>'Yes','No'=>'No','NA'=>'NA'],
                                        [
                                        'item' => function($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {

                                                $return = '<label>';
                                                $return .= '<input type="radio" name="' . $name . '" value="' . $value . '" tabindex="3">';

                                                $return .= '<span class="'.$value.'">' . ucwords($label) . '</span>';
                                                $return .= '</label>';

                                                return $return;
                                            }
                                        ]
                                        )

                                    ->label(false);
                                }else{
                                    if($model->wp_spost21 == 'Yes'){
                                        echo Html::img((\Yii::$app->params['statusimagepath']).'yes32.png');
                                    }
                                    elseif($model->wp_spost21 == 'No'){
                                        echo Html::img((\Yii::$app->params['statusimagepath']).'no32.png');
                                    }
                                    elseif($model->wp_spost21 == 'NA'){
                                        echo Html::img((\Yii::$app->params['statusimagepath']).'na32.png');
                                    }
                                }
                            ?>
                        </div>
```

CSS

```
.boxradio label input
{
  display:none;
}

.boxradio label span
{
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 35px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.boxradio label input:checked + span 
{
  border: 1px solid #008eff;
}

.boxradio label input:checked + span:before
{
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background: #008eff;
  z-index: -1;
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.boxradio label input:checked + span:after
{
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background: #008eff;
  z-index: -1;
  filter: blur(7px);
}

.boxradio label input:checked + span.Yes
{
  color: #00802b;
  border-color: #00802b;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px #00802b;
}

.boxradio label input:checked + span.Yes:before,
.boxradio label input:checked + span.Yes:after
{
  background: #00802b;
}

.boxrdio label input[value="Yes"] + span {
  color: #00802b;
  border-color: #00802b;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px #00802b;
}

.boxradio label input:checked + span.No
{
  color: #992600;
  border-color: #992600;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px #992600;
}

.boxradio label input:checked + span.No:before,
.boxradio label input:checked + span.No:after
{
  background: #992600;
}

.boxradio label input:checked + span.NA
{
  color: #5F5858;
  border-color: #5F5858;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px #5F5858;
}

.boxradio label input:checked + span.NA:before,
.boxradio label input:checked + span.NA:after
{
  background: #5F5858;
}
```

This works good when I'm submitting the form for the first time. The radiobutton css is changed when I click any. But in case of update, when the form opens, I can't understand which radiobutton I checked at the time of submitting. I need to change the css of the button as per the data from the database.

The current update form looks like -
[image]

I want to look it by default like 
[image]

Please help.

Comment: Could you make a Fiddle of your working progress and explain a bit more about what you expect it to happen ? I didn't get if you need the radio-button to stay checked after submitting the form or you want the radio-button to change to another css style after submitting the form.

Comment: This code is working good when I'm filling up the form and submitting. If i want to update the form, and reopen the form, the radio buttons are not showing as checked. I want to see fhem checked when the form loads

Answer (score 0):

Then it's not about the CSS, you could use HTML5 and JavaScript to store the values on session using `sessionStorage.getItem()` and `sessionStorage.setItem()`, so it'd store the values of the radioboxes like the last session of that same page, I have answered a question on handling data using this method, check and see if you can apply it on what you need :

---

[Passing Data to Another Component OnClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56097431/passing-data-to-another-component-onclick/56097571#56097571)

---

Note that after submitting a form, normally your data is sent and the form is cleared, so all elements go back to their original state.

Answer (score 0):

You can add checked attribute like this:

```
 'item' => function($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {
       if ($checked) {
          $checkedText = 'checked="checked"';
       } else {
              $checkedText = '';
       }
      $return = '<label>';
      $return .= '<input type="radio" name="' . $name . '" value="' . $value . '" tabindex="3" '.$checkedText.'>';
      $return .= '<span class="'.$value.'">' . ucwords($label) . '</span>';
      $return .= '</label>';

     return $return;
   }
]
```